# Porque o evento do meu botão não inicia no Swing?

Tags: java, swing

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class main{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JButton bo = new JButton("Clique");
        frame.add(bo);
        frame.setSize(600,600);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    private void bo(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        JFrame a = new JFrame();
        a.setVisible(true);
        a.setSize(900,900);


    }

}
```

galera, porque o evento do meu botão não está funcionando? ele até compila, mas quando eu clico no botão "clique" ele nn abre a outra janela que eu pedi pra abrir;-;

Comment: e onde foi que vc associou um evento click no botão pra que ele funcione? está faltando isso

Comment: pode me dar um exemplo do que devo fazer?

Comment: precisa adicionar um "listener" para "escutar" os eventos do botão, nesse caso o click: `bo.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
  public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { ...seu codigo aqui.... } }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa noite!

Eu peguei seu código e fiz com que o botão "escutasse" a ação, com uma expressão LAMBDA simplifiquei algumas linhas, fazendo com que funcione...

```
private static javax.swing.JButton bo;

public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    bo = new javax.swing.JButton("Clique");
    frame.add(bo);
    frame.setSize(600,600);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    bo.addActionListener((java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) -> {
        JFrame a = new JFrame();
        a.setVisible(true);
        a.setSize(900,900);
    });

}
```

Em resumo você não estava fazendo com que seu botão "escutasse" a ação que era feita...
Espero que você entenda o que eu quis dizer!!

Comment: mt obrigado, me ajudou mt!